# I want to display graphs and compare them

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, static-libraries

[image]

Display the points at which they merge , I was not able to find any library .....

Answer (score 1):

Displaying any form of charts in iOS can be done in 2 ways.

1. Using webView to load a html string with the javascript files imported into it.
   Using stringByAppendingFormat you can change the data points and refresh the webview. 
   http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2012/02/create-charts-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps-using-fusioncharts-xt/
2. Using a library to display them Natively. Something like Charts by Daniel Iohen Gindi. It is a bit extensive so just use the line Charts in your case and ignore the others.
   https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Using the 2nd method (native) will always perform better, but the simplicity of html5 charts make it very easy to implement

To obtain points when lines meet is basically saying when 2 data has the same value. So you can just add an if statement and print the value out or store it as a variable.